# How to handle alert for SafariDriver in selenium?

Tags: java, macos, selenium, selenium-ide

Please Help me handle alert in safari

The result that I get in this following is that safari cannot handle alert so is there any other method to handle the alert

```
package Default;

import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

import org.openqa.selenium.Alert;
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.safari.SafariDriver;

public class Safari_demo {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException{

        WebDriver driver = new SafariDriver();

        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

        driver.get("http://www.htmlite.com/JS002.php");

        Thread.sleep(6000);

        Alert alert = driver.switchTo().alert();
        alert.accept();

        driver.close();
    }

}
```

Comment: Any solution? It seems not supported which fully limits a lot of Selenium testing for Safari

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to *[explicitly wait for the alert to appear](http://selenium.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/support/ui/ExpectedConditions.html#alertIsPresent())*:

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 30);
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.alertIsPresent());

Alert alert = driver.switchTo().alert();
```

Comment: @ShiyadShafee what are the symptoms?